# start xticks_labels from right side of a subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

Created few subplots(9*2) of horizontal barplot using seaborn.

```
sns.barplot( x= state_commod_Df['Total'], y= state_commod_Df.index, orient= 'h', ax =ax[index], palette = "winter_r", edgecolor  = 'black')

# Plot Customization
ax[index].set_xlabel('Total NO.', color = 'maroon', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 13.5, labelpad= 20)
ax[index].set_ylabel('Commodities', color = 'maroon', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 13.5, labelpad= 20)

ax[index].set_yticklabels( labels= state_commod_Df.index, color = 'darkolivegreen', fontsize= 13.5, fontweight = 'bold' )
ax[index].set_xticklabels( labels= state_commod_Df['Total'], color = 'darkolivegreen', fontsize= 10, fontweight = 'bold' )
```

Produced the following image:
[subplots_fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmDLq.png)
The Problem is that all the xticks labels are starting from left to right with descending order. It happened because my [state_commod_Df['Total']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91uY5.png) have values in descending order.
Now my question is how to start the xtickcs_labels from right side of subplots so that it matches with bars ??

Comment: If you post code we can run, we will be better able to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @J_H Here is the link of the notebook -  The mentioned code is in last cell https://nbviewer.org/github/sanjuirm/India_Commodity/tree/main/

Comment: Assigning those values to the x tick labels doesn't make sense as the dataframe values don't correspond to the numeric positions in the x-axis. To change the font, you could use `ax[index].set_xticklabels(ax[index].get_xticklabels(), color='red', fontsize=...)`.

Comment: @JohanC I did what you asked me to do. But it gave me only blank ticks with no labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `set_xticklabels()`. As you are setting it post plotting and you have set it to descending, it will overwrite. I believe you need to use it for color, font, etc. So, you can use `set_tick_params` and `set_fontweight()`. The updated code is as below. Note that I have only taken one state and run this, so the axis is just ax, not ax[index]

**ADDITIONAL**
I was also expecting @JohanC's steps (get_ticklabels) to work. But, for some reason, as soon as the set_ticklabels() are added, these labels become blanks. Could be a bug. So, this is a workaround for that...

```
#state_commod_Df.reset_index(inplace=True)
#state_commod_Df = state_commod_Df.rename(columns = {'index':'Metal'})

ax=sns.barplot(x=state_commod_Df.Total, y= state_commod_Df.index, palette = "winter_r", edgecolor  = 'black')
# Plot Customization
ax.set_xlabel('Total NO.', color = 'maroon', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 13.5, labelpad= 20)
ax.set_ylabel('Commodities', color = 'maroon', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 13.5, labelpad= 20)

ax.set_yticklabels( labels = state_commod_Df.index, color = 'darkolivegreen', fontsize= 13.5, fontweight = 'bold' )

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelcolor='darkolivegreen', labelsize=10 )
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in labels: label.set_fontweight('bold')

#mylabels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
#print(mylabels)
#mylabels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
#print(mylabels)
#ax.set_xticklabels(labels = labels, color = 'darkolivegreen', fontsize= 10, fontweight = 'bold' )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are right about the overwriting. Actually, I had thought about this issue but was so exhausted with constantly getting error that I stopped looking and left the plot with no X-axis tick labels. But now It's working. Thank  you for the answer.